# Classic ASP "or" keyword

Tags: asp-classic, keyword

I was just wondering - is the or keyword exclusive?

I mean like given the following:

```
if x or y then
```

Would this return true if both x and y were true? Or is it that one *or* the other but *not both* has to be true to execute the code inside the if?

Comment: I have tried Googling this and am getting mixed answers - some places say it must be at least one is true, some say just one must be true..

Comment: ASP has an xor operator. I'm not aware of any programming language where "or" isn't meant in the logical sense; the ambiguity only exists in natural languages (in English; "or" usually means xor).

Comment: Thanks for the info Wooble. I have since discovered that, after remembering the keyword I was trying to think of (operators) - on searching that up I found out what it means. Unfortunately searching up ASP or keyword filters out the or in Google! Post this as an answer and I will up-vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard OR operator is NOT exclusive: `True or True` gives `True`.

Comment: Thanks Konerak; sorry I didn't come back to mark this as the answer sooner - see my comment above for the reason.